# Combining vectors with analogous names

Tags: r

I'm not familiar with R code and I have tried to solve this problem without success. Please help me!

If I have this kind of vector

```
> x1 <- c(5,7,9)
> x2 <- c(6,3,4)
....
> xn <- c(1,2,3)
```

and I like to combine them

> result <- cbind(x1, x2, ..., xn)

How to say this **x1, x2, ..., xn**?

Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

You could use `ls` with the pattern argument

```
x.data <- ls(pattern='^x.?')
```

This returns a list of names that can be used with `get` and `sapply`

```
sapply(x.data, get)
#  x1 x2 xn
# [1,]  5  6  1
# [2,]  7  3  2
# [3,]  9  4  3
```

Comment: and therefore `do.call(cbind,lapply(x.data,get))`, following from @Tommy's answer ...

Comment: also note that your pattern matching will put `x10` before `x9` because `ls` sorts alphabetically. Instead, I would consider using `x.data <- paste("x", seq_len(n) sep = "")`. My understanding of the question is that the original poster already knows what `n` is, and just wants to avoid typing a very long `cbind(x1, x2, ..., xn)`.

Answer (score 4):

Although it is possible to solve that problem, the real solution is probably to use another way to store your vectors. How did you get them?

Typically it is better to have your vectors in a list structure than as separate global variables when you have more than a few.

Here's one way

```
x <- list(x1 = c(5,7,9), x2=c(6,3,4), xn=c(1,2,3))

x$x2 # the x2 vector
str(x) # prints an overview of x

# combine them into a matrix
do.call(cbind, x)
```

This is one way to read in a bunch of vectors from files into a list:

```
# Read in 10 vectors into x
x <- lapply(1:10, function(i) scan(paste("myvec",i,".txt", sep=""))
x[[3]] # the vector in myvec3.txt
str(x) # prints an overview of x
```

Answer (score 0):

`c(x1, x2, ... xn)`

```
> x1 <- c(5,7,9)
> 
> x2 <- c(6,3,4)
>
> xn <- c(1,2,3)
> c(x1, x2, xn)
[1] 5 7 9 6 3 4 1 2 3
> 
> matrix(c(x1, x2, xn), ncol=3)
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    5    6    1
[2,]    7    3    2
[3,]    9    4    3
>
```